# SVG-Animation in safari with img-tag not always working

Tags: html, animation, svg, safari

i have a problem with a svg-image with animation.

the image is stored on my server like "ajax-loader.svg" and i show the animated svg with a normal -tag like:

```
<img src="images/ajax-loader.svg" />
```

problem: 
the first times when i call the site, the animation is showing correctly. but after 2-3 site-calls, i only see a static image and no animation and i don't know why?

svg-code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="44px" height="44px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-default"><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(0 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(30 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.08333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(60 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.16666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(90 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(120 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.3333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(150 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.4166666666666667s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(210 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.5833333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(240 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.6666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(270 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(300 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.8333333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect><rect x="46.5" y="40" width="7" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(330 50 50) translate(0 -30)">  <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0.9166666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></rect></svg>
```

Comment: report it as a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Comment: no its only in safari on macOS Sierra, but i had the problem on older OS too. so i used a animated gif-image but i wanna change to animated-svg.

Comment: report it then, there's not much else you can do unless you want to download the source and fix it.

Comment: ok report it, thank you Robert Longson!